# How can I save in Ansible variable the output from a bash command?

Tags: azure, ansible

I would like to store the content of a step of my Azure pipeline into a variable:

```
steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'
- script: |
    echo 'hi'
  displayName: 'Salute'
- name: Save output to variable
  shell: echo 'hi'
  register: salute
```

But what I get is:
Unexpected value 'name'.

I also tried set_fact but what I get is:

```
Unexpected value 'set_fact'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Pipeline is not Ansible. Refer to [Azure Pipeline documentation on how to set variables in scripts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks)